# How to compare the past value of the output?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Can someone know how to compare the image below, i got a hard time solving this. :) Thank you so much :)

The output is inside the for loop. I just want to compare and count.

Sample code below.

```js
var array_date = ["2018/03/07","2018/03/07","2018/03/07","2018/03/07","2018/03/07","2018/03/08","2018/03/09","2018/03/09"];

var eventType = ["Absent","Absent","Late","Late","Late","Absent","Absent","Late"];

var prev_array_date="";
var prev_eventType="";
for(i = 0; i <array_date.length; i++){
console.log("sort_unique_arr_date[b]: "+array_date[i]);
console.log("temp_eventType: "+eventType[i]);
console.log("---------------------------------------------------------")

if(prev_array_date == "" && prev_eventType == ""){
prev_array_date = array_date[i];
prev_eventType = eventType[i];

}else{
  if(prev_array_date == array_date[i] && prev_eventType == eventType[i]){
  
  }
  else{
  
  }

}



}
```

I just want the output like this:

```
Output:

2018/03/07
Absent - 2

2018/03/07
Late - 3

2018/03/08
Absent - 1

2018/03/09
Absent - 1

2018/03/09
Late - 1
```

[Console image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9200.png)

Comment: `The output is inside the for loop`...where is the for loop? Better explain what you are trying to achieve and what you are getting instead

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you want to access the value from the previous iteration. In that case, adding a `var prev_date = current_date` at below the rest of your code. That way it won't be reassigned until after your logic is executed and it will hold the value from the previous iteration

Comment: @Yuri i just updated the sample code

Comment: that will count on how many are the same value.

Comment: You don't need to save the `prev_date` value if you know the offset from current index and the index that you need to compare, in an array iteratoin.
use: `array[i-1]` to know the value of the previous iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use date and type as index in an object, and easily fill it as desired.
Try with the following code, it should do what you want

```
var array_date = ["2018/03/07","2018/03/07","2018/03/07","2018/03/07","2018/03/07","2018/03/08","2018/03/09","2018/03/09"];

var eventType = ["Absent","Absent","Late","Late","Late","Absent","Absent","Late"];

var count_obj = {};
for(i = 0; i <array_date.length; i++){
  console.log("sort_unique_arr_date[b]: "+array_date[i]);
  console.log("temp_eventType: "+eventType[i]);
  console.log("---------------------------------------------------");
  let key = array_date[i];
  let s_key = eventType[i];
  if( ! count_obj.hasOwnProperty(key) ){
        count_obj[ key ] = {};
  }
  if( ! count_obj[ key ].hasOwnProperty(s_key) ){
        count_obj[ key ][ s_key ] = 0;
  }

    count_obj[ key ][ s_key ] += 1;

}
console.log("--OUTPUT BELOW--");
for( date in count_obj){
    console.log(date);
    for( type in count_obj[date] ){
        // if you put 'console.log(date);' here you'll have exactly the output you wanted
        console.log(type +' - '+count_obj[date][type]);
    }
}
```

Check the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6jkj0vzt/11/)

Comment: how would i separate each date, just like the output i gave??